# mySql procedure condition does not occur

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in MySql..

```
main: BEGIN
  DECLARE user_name VARCHAR(65);
  DECLARE home_path VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE home_perm VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE num_posts, param_index INT(10);

  SELECT `account`, `Posts`
    INTO user_name, num_posts
    FROM account_info
    WHERE account = username_in AND password = password_in;

  IF (user_name = NULL) OR (user_name != username_in) THEN
    LEAVE main;
  END IF;

  SET home_perm = 'LRS';

  IF num_posts > 100 THEN
    SET param_index = 1;
    SET home_path = 'c:\\folder_1';
  ELSEIF num_posts > 200 THEN
    SET param_index = 2;
    SET home_path = 'c:\\folder_2';
  ELSE
    SET param_index = 0;
    SET home_path = 'c:\\folder_0';
  END IF;

  SELECT home_path,home_perm,param_index;

END
```

When I test this procedure with a username that is incorrect I want it to "LEAVE main" but even if I do that it still does not enter LEAVE main, what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` value does not equal to anything, therefore both comparisons will return false. Use either the [is null](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) operator, or [<=>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator to compare a variable with null.

```
user_name IS NULL
```